How to add a new calculated column on the an existing table as a max value of an existing column
I am new to a SQL and I would like to ask you for a help.
I have a table with around more than 10 millions records for multiple fiscal years.For each fiscal year, I have a fiscal period and a posting period columns.
I need to convert the following DAX code to SQL code. I need to add a new columns to the existing table to hold the MaxPeriodValue (Yes/No), based on a calculation which finds first the maximum fiscal period and compares it to all Posting Period and assign a Yes if the posting_key equals to the maximum period.
MaxPeriodValue =
    'TableName'[Posting_Key] = CALCULATE(MAX('TableName'[Fiscal Period]),ALLEXCEPT('TableName','TableName'[FiscalYear]))

TableName contains data for multiple fiscal years. For each fiscal year, there are multiple Fiscal periods and multiple posting keys.
What I need is a Yes/No answer.

The first step is to calculate the Max value of all the fiscal periods for all the fiscal years.

The second step  is to compare each value in the Posting_key  column. If any of the values in the Posting_key column = Max(Fiscal Period), then the MaxPeriodValue = true else it is false.


For instance if the Max(Fiscal Period = 14) and I have value in the posting_key which is 14, I will have the following value in the table:
enter image description here
Thanks for your help!
I tried to existing solution in PowerQuery, it did not work for me.

You probably can't do it as a computed column since you need info outside the current row. A view would work. You didn't specify your platform.

In SQL, columns can be calculated only using values within the same row. Therefore, it is impossible to reference values from other rows or perform aggregation functions such as finding the maximum value across multiple rows.
In your case where you need to derive a column based on information outside the current row, you can utilise a view or a stored procedure.
A view would be a good option if you need a virtual representation of the data with the calculated column included. You can query this view whenever you need the data, and this view will include the calculated column, such as MaxPeriodValue.
Alternatively, If you prefer to have the calculated column as part of the actual table, you can use a stored procedure to update the table.

You can use window functions
CASE WHEN
  Posting_Key = MAX(FiscalPeriod) OVER ()
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Or
CASE WHEN
  Posting_Key = FIRST_VALUE(FiscalPeriod) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalPeriod DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

